# Does VPN Service on a "Standard" OS X Server use L2TP or PP2P?

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, osx-leopard, l2tp

Does VPN Service on a "Standard" OS X Server use L2TP or PP2P?

Comment: i'm answering my own question here as it might come in handy for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X 10.5 and Mac OS X 10.6 Server, when configured as "Standard" will use "L2TP over IPSec." After you have saved your VPN ".internetconnect" configuration file from Server Prefences, you can inspect its settings manually by opening it in a text editor.

The newest version, OS X 10.7 Lion Server also uses "L2TP over IPSec" — in fact, in Lion Server, ["PPTP" can not be configured using the GUI](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4748).

Answer (score 1):

It has both L2TP over IPSEC and PPTP support.  Generally when connecting from Mac OS X the client would use the L2TP over IPSEC option and Windows clients would use PPTP.  You have to enable them seperately in the Server Admin interface by enabling them in the L2TP and PPTP tabs and assigning IP ranges etc. to each connection type.  So depending on the clients connecting would determine which of these you would enable or if you need to enable both.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but what you write is only true when you've configured an "Advanced" server. You shouldn't really being using "Server Admin.app" with a "Standard" config, you should be using "Server Preferences.app" which, to my knowledge, does not give you an option to configure PPTP